# Displaying multiple custom markers when multiple copies of the world are visible with Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

I've created a custom OverlayView that houses a canvas element using an approach similar to the one found [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/canvaslayer/?r=377). Everything is working accordingly, but I'm looking for some advice on how to handle situations where multiple versions of the world can be seen at lower zoom levels. Currently I translate my canvas element like so:

```
this.topLeft = new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getNorthEast().lat(), bounds.getSouthWest().lng());
var divTopLeft = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.topLeft);
this.canvas.style[this.cssTransformPrefix] = 'translate(' + Math.floor(divTopLeft.x) + 'px,' + Math.floor(divTopLeft.y) + 'px)';
```

To position and draw one of my custom markers, I use the following approach:

```
var scale = Math.pow(2, map.zoom);
var offset = mapProjection.fromLatLngToPoint(this.centerPoint);

this.pxTopLeft.x = Math.floor(offset.x*scale);
this.pxTopLeft.y = Math.floor(offset.y*scale);

var worldPoint = mapProjection.fromLatLngToPoint(marker.position());
marker.draw(Math.floor(-this.pxTopLeft.x + worldPoint.x*scale), Math.floor(-this.pxTopLeft.y + worldPoint.y*scale));
```

Using this behaviour my canvas-rendered markers will snap from one world instance to the next when the user pans the map. Instead, what I'd like to achieve is something similar to the native Google marker behaviour whereby markers are plotted once for each representation of the world. Unfortunately, using native Google markers isn't possible. How can I achieve this?